# Irrational winding of a torus

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto T=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $x \mapsto (x,\alpha x) \, \, \mod \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\alpha$ irrational. I want to prove that $f$ isn't an embedding. In order to do this, my idea is to prove that $f(0)$ is a cluster point of $f(\mathbb{Z}$.

I know the existence of this fact:

$\operatorname{inf}_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} |b+m-\alpha(a+n)|=0$ for every $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

May I use this fact to show that $f(0)$ is a cluster point of $f(\mathbb{Z}$)?